# Defining a global object using IIFE

Tags: javascript

I found 2 ways to define a global object using IIFE, like these:

```
(function () {
    var func = function () { };

    window.func = func;
}());
```

vs:

```
(function (myFunc) {

    window.func = myFunc();

}(function () {
    var func = function () { };

    return func;
}));
```

I notice that almost js famous plugins use the second way, ex: jquery:

[image: 1]

Why's that?

Comment: What are “almost” JS plugins? This is mostly a matter of taste. I’ve used this way when I needed a single expression (that an IIFE is) where certain variables are referred to multiple times. I could’ve written this differently.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's clearly a visual matter. [UMD](https://github.com/umdjs/umd) code may support multiple module patterns.

The second approach separates the UMD code from the module code. By opening the corresponding module file, one can see at the top, in one place, which module patterns are supported.